# How can I make Entity Framework 6 populate a Dictionary<string,object> from custom DB fields?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, dictionary, odata

**Problem**: My Entity has some custom DB fields that are unknown at compile time, that I need put into a `Dictionary<string,object>`.

**Background**:
The data is coming from a view (no need for CUD functionality) in SQL Server. There are over a hundred known constant fields, and a few that are custom (can change per user or over time). The view has no proper key, and EF treats all non-nullable fields (over 30) as the de facto composite key.

Ultimately, the `DbContext` is being passed as an `IQueryable` to an OData Web API, which builds the query (which is then executed in SQL Server, not in-memory). I don't want to retrieve and attach the custom fields subsequent to getting the main entities, as that would entail a large number of ugly, manually constructed SQL queries. I'd also prefer to avoid having to deconstruct the OData query into SQL select statements and manually querying the DB, mapping the results into POCO etc.

I was hoping EF had some way of specifying/modifying the mapping between raw datarow and entity, so I could intercept the custom fields and populate the Dictionary myself. EF's Interceptors seemed like a good candidate, as they offered access to data readers, but they don't seem to give access to the respective Entities. Likewise, the `ObjectMaterialized` event gives you the Entity, but not the source data. This use case may not be the most common, but it seems simple enough to me that I'm surprised EF's more advanced functionality (Interceptors, event) can't handle it.

Is there something I'm overlooking, or do I have to wait for EF Core to finally get Property Bag support?

Comment: Not sure what you want. can you show us an example?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such option. Also, EF states all columns explicitly in Select (it doesn't ever do "select *").

Comment: True, though I figure that's one thing the Interceptors CAN fix relatively easily